# Resize vs mirror

Tags: modifiers, geometry

A question from a beginner. I want to move 2 selected edges by the same distance.
[image]
In the first case, I perform a resize on the X-axis.
[image]
And in the second case, I divide the part in half, and then add the mirror modifier and apply this modifier.
[image]
Is there a difference for geometry between these two actions?

Comment: When you "divide the part in half" (I guess by creating a loopcut? or knife..), the new edge belongs to the original face. If you have an existing couple of edges and scale on X, you are creating a fold in the original face surface. Have you tried to switch off the subsurf modifier and compare the two methods?

Comment: It's probably worth clarifying that I divide the part in half by highlighting the two edges of the left part of the detail, and then remove the vertices. In the right part, I just move the second edge using the g key, and then use the mirror modifier. With the subsurf modifier disabled, I looked and don't see much difference...